# Apache removing trailing slashes in vhost.conf vs .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With Apache 2.2.15, I use the following in a root level .htaccess file to remove trailing slashes from URLs:

```
# Remove trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I move the rules to a VirtualHost block in my vhost.conf, I get a "Too many redirects" error when accessing a directory.

Can somebody please explain why this is happening?

Comment: A side note here, independent of your question: rewrite rules in the configuration have the advantage over `.htaccess` style files that the work on _absolute_ paths. So paths including the leading slash. Your rewrite rule doubles that slash. That does not make any sense, although it probably does not really cause problems, since the components should be robust enough to deal with that...

Comment: I am guessing here, but I could imagine that the reason for the endless redirect is that you have the enabled the index option. That one takes care to automatically add a missing trailing slash if the request targets a directory in the file system. I guess you can see the issue here...

Comment: I did try some variations: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`, `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]`. Also my understanding of the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` rule is to prevent this from happening on directories that actually exist on the file system.

Comment: Hm... you _did_ restart the http server after changing the configuration?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the http server.